# ssh stops in btw while commands specified in a function

Tags: fish

**~/.config/fish/config.fish**

```
function start
  nohup VBoxHeadless -startvm $argv
end
function stop
  VBoxManage controlvm $argv poweroff
end
function vm
  stop vm18 & start vm18 ; sshpass -p vm18 ssh archvm
end
```

**Test:**

```
$ vm
VBoxManage: error: Machine 'vm18' is not currently running
appending output to nohup.out
```

It never does ssh for some reason. However after the machine has started if I do

```
$ sshpass -p vm18 ssh archvm
```

it works perfectly.

I don't understand why, and how to fix. I assuming `appending output` thing stops from running the next command.

One way to fix this is: add `&` in start

```
function start
  nohup VBoxHeadless -startvm $argv &
end
```

Though I don't know why that works.

Comment: Are you running `stop` in the background for a reason? I'd try `funcion vm; stop vm18; start vm18; and sshpass -p vm19 ssh archvm; end`

Comment: Unfortunately fish functions cannot be backgrounded - see [this issue](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/238). Backgrounding the command within the function (per your "one way to fix this") will allow it to execute in the background.